# ic_launcher not displaying correct icon

Tags: android, icons

The test icon is being shown on an Android device with mdpi. But on a Samsung S8 with xxxhdpi the "default" icon is shown. What could be the issue?

```
src/tst/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png (48 x 48)
src/tst/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (192 x 192)
```

Comment: look in ur manifest and see which image its using.

Comment: Check all the icons and its related sizes wrt pixels, as it is auto fetched based on screen size, you cannot place the icons programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the new Adaptive icon introduced in Android 8.0, this made the icon not showing correctly.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive